# Получение строкового ресурса с параметрами

Tags: android, строки

Раньше использовал конструкцию:

```
return (getResources().getString(R.string.added_obj, entries.size()));
```

сама строка

```
<string name="added_obj">%1$s objects added</string>
```

Сейчас получаю ошибку:

> Suspicious argument type for formatting argument #1 in `added_obj`: conversion is `s`, received `int` (argument #2 in method call) (Did you mean formatting character `d`, 'o' or `x`?).

Что он от меня хочет и как это надо оформлять?

Comment: Замени `%1$s objects added` на `%1$d objects added`

Comment: На заметку: в документации к классу [java.util.Formatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) детально описан синтаксис

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
<string name="added_obj">%1$d objects added</string>
```

потому как `%1$s` говорит о том что первый параметр ожидается `String`,
но вы передаете `entries.size()`  типа `int` в качестве аргумента.